# c# Function with Type as Parameter? Cant use it in Task

Tags: c#, class, types, task, observablecollection

Hey I have tried to use a Type as Parameter and using `typeof(Class)` to get the type.

My problem is that i cant use the Type in a Task like this:

```
CreditorList = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();
```

Is this possible??

Code for Reference:

```
private void Dg_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CreateList(typeof(CreditorClient));
        }    

async private void CreateList(Type DataModel)
        {
            CreditorList = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();
        }
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '...OberservableCollection' to '...DataModel.CreditorClient'

Comment: What type is CreditorList  ?

Comment: Why not use `ObservableCollection<object>`?

Comment: This is almost never the right thing to do. Even having created the object successfully, you will have trouble actually _using_ the object if you can't statically declare the generic type for variables which will be used to access the object. But, if you insist, this is an all-too-often posted question. One of the earliest duplicates is shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly you would have to use reflection to create the list it you want to pass it as a `Type`.

```
CreditorList = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(DataModel))
```

I would recommend you find a design where this is not required though. Reflection is slow and ugly and you might run into problems with it.

Comment: shows same error... just with object instead of OberservableCollection

Comment: That is why I asked for the type of `CreditorList` you have to cast it to that type .. hopefully some interface the `ObservableCollection` implements that has no generic arguments, otherwise this is not apluicable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use reflection:

```
private void Dg_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CreateList(typeof(CreditorClient));
}    

async private void CreateList(Type DataModel)
{
    Type genericType = typeof(ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(DataModel);
    CreditorList = new ObservableCollection<Activator.CreateInstance(genericType)>();
}
```

Comment: Same Error.....

Comment: What type is CreditorList?

Comment: Im not Sure.. when i try making a break point on typeof(CreditorList) i gives me the path to the class...

Comment: How are you defining CreditorList? It looks like some global variable in you example.

Comment: `public ObservableCollection<CreditorClient> CreditorList { get; set; }`

Comment: Why do you want to pass type as argument when you have variable defined like this?

Comment: Yea just noticed that, what i want is to Call `CreateList()` with an argument like `CreateList(CreditorClient)` or `CreateList(DebtorClient)` and get a list i can put into a grid. The Classes `CreditorClient` and `DebtorClient` is a class with Get Set Variables

Comment: Does `CreditorClient` and `Debtor Client` have common supertype? If so, you can use that supertype in definition of `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: How do i find out?

Comment: Look to `CreditorClient` class. Is there something like `public class CreditorClient : Client`?

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following code:

```
private void Dg_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CreateList<CreditorClient>();
        }    

async private void CreateList<TModel>()
        {
            CreditorList = new ObservableCollection<TModel>();
        }
```

Comment: shows same error... just with <TModel> instead of OberservableCollection